# How to use execute statement using select into in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I tried to search some post but i got no lucky to find like my scenario:

This is my attempt but no luck.

```
declare @tb varchar(30)
set @tb = 'newtablename'
declare @sql varchar(30) = 'select * into ' + @tb + ' from tbl_3;'
EXEC  sp_executesql  @sql
```

it returns an error

> Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type
>   'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring your `@tb` and `@sql` variables as type `varchar(30)`. The error clearly warns that it expects ntext, nchar, or nvarchar. Also, your `@sql` string would be truncated at length 30. I would suggest changing your code to the following:

```
declare @tb nvarchar(30)
set @tb = 'newtablename'
declare @sql nvarchar(255) = 'select * into ' + @tb + ' from tbl_3;'
EXEC  sp_executesql  @sql
```